# Geography ST_Intersects causes "Boom! Could not generate outside point!"

Tags: postgis, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to find where a user is based on their point and a table of multi polygons.

I currently have:

```
SELECT u.name l.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN locations AS l
ON ST_Intersects(u.location, l.geog)
```

Where both u.location and l.geog are of type geography.

And I get the Error

> Boom! Could not generate outside point

I've created a new table with just one user in and one multi polygon in and it's still triggering the above error.

If I go back to the original location set and add ::geometry, the point seems to land in 23 out of the 28 possible multi polygons which is also incorrect.

Could you direct me in what I'm doing wrong?

---

I first moved to geom and the issue persisted (not the boom, but the random returning of polygons).

I discovered the issue.

The data I was using was in the format 27700 but it didn't have a set SRID of 27700.

So to make this work, I had to explicitly set it to the correct SRID before changing:

```
SELECT u.name l.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN locations AS l
ON ST_Intersects(u.location, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(l.geom,27700),4326))
```

Comment: Which version of postgis are you using? Can you show the exact data (as EWKT) you are trying to use?

Comment: Here is the multipolygon: `https://pastebin.com/P1ypTnPV`. here is the point `Point(-0.140721,51.484313)`. Version = `POSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTERPOSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTER`

Comment: Is that MultiPolygon valid?

Comment: Please update the question, not with a link, but with the real multipolygon EWKT. It avoids things going stale, and dubious stuff in pastebin.

Comment: I updated the question with the discovered answer: I had to explicitly cast the SRID to it's original format before setting a new SRID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my reading of:

- [Certain MultiPolygons cause “BOOM! Could not generate outside point!” in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9217)
- [PostGIS ERROR: BOOM! Could not generate outside point!](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24615) and
- [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.postgis/27073).

As Brad has suggested, posting the WKT of the offending geometries, and also the version of Postgres and PostGIS would be helpful.

What is likely the case is that you're experiencing a bug. The BOOM error message was included, possibly late at night, but Paul Ramsey because he didn't expect this error to occur. It's essentially a joke (but not funny, because you're experiencing it!)

So, you could narrow down the offending geometry, and use this as a repeatable case to do a bug report.

As a short term fix, you can try casting to geometry (you are using geography, right?) as the bug doesn't appear to exist for geometry. (Note that geometry handles lat, lon, it just doesn't handle spherical calculations, as far as I understand.)

Comment: Here is the multipolygon: `https://pastebin.com/P1ypTnPV`. here is the point `Point(-0.140721,51.484313)`. Version = `POSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTERPOSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" RASTER`

Comment: On the geometry front, I run this: `SELECT u.name l.name FROM users u INNER JOIN locations AS l ON ST_Intersects(u.location::geometry, l.geog::geometry)` but it returns that the user is a member of 23 areas which it is not.

Comment: Finally, if I just do `select st_intersects(copied_polygon_geog,copied_user_geog)` it returns true for the correct one and returns false for the incorrect polygons. It seems to fall down on the join

Comment: Hey @Bill, this information is better placed in your original question.

Comment: I updated the question with the discovered answer: I had to explicitly cast the SRID to it's original format before setting a new SRID.